Fill in Between moves legend and title
I have a weird issue when I try to use fill between. without using it my graph just draws perfect but if I want to fill the area between my two curves, the graph moves the legend and title an also kind of change size.

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}    [grid,
            minor tick num = 5,
            enlargelimits = false,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny,fill=white},
            restrict y to domain = -10:10,
            xlabel = {$r$},
            ylabel = {$a$},
            title = {Regions of Fixed Points at $a^2 + 4r < 0$},
            title style = {font=\tiny,fill=white},
            legend pos = outer north east]
            \addplot[draw = none, pattern = north east lines, area legend] {1};
            \legend {One $x^{*}$};
            \addplot [name path = A, domain = -10:0, red] {(4*(-x))^(0.5)};
            \addplot [name path = B, domain = -10:0, red] {-(4*(-x))^(0.5)};
            \addplot [draw = none, pattern = north east lines] fill between [of = A and B, domain = -10:0];
            \addplot [mark=none, forget plot, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(-10,0) (10,0)};
            \addplot [mark=none, forget plot, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0,-10) (0,10)};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


Welcome. // Please add the missing lines so your code will compile. Thank you

The issue is caused by the scaling.
As answered here, move the scale=1.5 from tikzpiture options to axis options
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.5] % <--- removed
    \begin{axis}    [grid,
      minor tick num = 5,
      enlargelimits = false,
      ticklabel style = {font=\tiny,fill=white},
      restrict y to domain = -10:10,
      xlabel = {$r$},
      ylabel = {$a$},
      title = {Regions of Fixed Points at $a^2 + 4r < 0$},
      title style = {font=\tiny,fill=white},
      legend pos = outer north east,
      scale=1.5] % <--- added
      \addplot[draw = none, pattern = north east lines, area legend] {1};
      \legend {One $x^{*}$};
      \addplot [name path = A, domain = -10:0, red] {(4*(-x))^(0.5)};
      \addplot [name path = B, domain = -10:0, red] {-(4*(-x))^(0.5)};
      \addplot [draw = none, pattern = north east lines] fill between [of = A and B, domain = -10:0];
      \addplot [mark=none, forget plot, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(-10,0) (10,0)};
      \addplot [mark=none, forget plot, black, thick, dotted] coordinates {(0,-10) (0,10)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks! It works perfectly.
